# Create invoice attachment file in Coupa using REST API from Power Automate HTTP Action

Tags: power-automate, coupa

I am trying to upload/create an attachment to Coupa Invoice record from Power Automate using REST API. From `[Coupa documentation][1]`, we have reference to create attachment using CURL.
The following example post creates an attachment of the file, Standard_Terms_Conditions.pdf, for the contract 12345.

curl -X POST 
https:///api/requisitions/12345/attachments 
-H "Accept: application/xml" 
-H "content-type: multipart/form-data" 
-H "x-coupa-api-key: " 
-F "attachment[file]=@/Users/IntegrationAdmin/Contracts/Standard_Terms_Conditions.pdf" 
-F "attachment[type]=file"
-F "attachment[intent]=Supplier"

I would like to create the attachment from Power Automate and reading the file content from an email/ OneDriveforBusiness. Any suggestions/ inputs on this would be really helpful.

I am using below format to upload the file. But things are moving as expected into the target system.

{
"file": {
"intent": "invoice_attachment",
"linked-to": {
"type": "invoice_header",
"id": "333072"
},
"file": {
"filename": "invoice.pdf",
"content": "{base64(content)}"
}
}
}